# Is it possible write commentary using SnakeYaml?

Tags: java

I was writing code for studying YAML files, and I'm trying to put a comment in the YAML file, but I just found out that it doesn't work the way it does.

My doubts are:
It is possible to insert comments when writing a document.
Am I doing it right?
If it is not possible with the SnakeYaml API, what other method is more plausible.

Codes

JAVA CODE

```
try {

    text = "#Some random Comentary" 
         +  "Something: Something\n"
         +  "RandoText: Goes Here\n"
         +  "Number: true\n"
         +  "sometext: Something Else";

    Object obj = writeYaml.load(text);

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(directoryPath);

    writeYaml.dump(obj, writer);

} catch (Exception e) {}
```

YAML was create

```
{RandoText: Goes Here, Number: true, sometext: Something Else}
```

YAML I want create

```
{
      #Some random Comentary
      RandoText: Goes Here, 
      Number: true, 
      sometext: Something Else
    }
```

Comment: By commentary do you meant generate comments in YAML files based on your business logic specified in Java?

Comment: I just want put some comments in yml file, but every time that I try, line breaks and comments not work. All yml file are saved on a single-line format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem, it is not the most plausible but let's get to the result.

I was reading the Snakeyaml documentation (I don't know if it was the official documentation), but it said that the documentation was out of date, so it wasn't much help.

So I decided to write the document by hand, my code ended up being like this:

```
try {

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("filename.yaml");

    String text = "#Some random Cometary\n"
                + "RandomText: Goes Here,\n"
                + "Number: 10,\n"
                + "isBoolean: true";

    fileWriter.write(text);
    fileWriter.close();


} catch (Exception e) {};
```

But I do not intend to abandon SnakeYaml for now, due to the fact of being able to read Yaml without having to waste time dealing with texot, Snake Yaml already does that, there is no reason to rewrite the text.

However, if someone has any other better method, give me a warning that will always be welcome.

ah! when I forget to say, I tried to make a document clone, but these documents do not go with the jar file when you close the project build.